# SlimDX GDI Bitmap to Direct2D Bitmap is scale ~ 1.5 - 2 X

Tags: graphics, directx, gdi, slimdx, direct2d

I'm using the code on https://code.google.com/p/slimdx/issues/detail?id=707 to convert a System.Drawing.Bitmap to a SlimDX.Direct2D.Bitmap. I've used the *E* **X** *A* **C** *T* **L** *Y* the same code before and if worked perfectly. Now, when I draw the image with

```
Dim TheBitmap As SlimDX.Direct2D.Bitmap = LoadBitmap(New Bitmap(New MemoryStream(TheBytesThatIGotOffTheNetworkStream)))
SlimDX.Direct2D.WindowRenderTarget.DrawBitmap(TheBitmap)
```

I get a Bitmap that has been scaled 1.5 to 2 times. If I save the System.Drawing.Bitmap, it's perfect. I've done this before, and it never scaled. I even tried getting rid of the stream and loading a bitmap from the hard disc. It didn't work. Thanks.

My code:

Form1.vb:

```
Imports SlimDX
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.IO
Public Class Form1
    Dim F As Direct2D.Factory
    Dim WRTP As Direct2D.WindowRenderTargetProperties
    Dim WRT As Direct2D.WindowRenderTarget
    Dim TheBitmap As Direct2D.Bitmap
    Function LoadBitmap(drawingBitmap As Bitmap) As Direct2D.Bitmap
        Dim result As Direct2D.Bitmap = Nothing
        Dim drawingBitmapData As BitmapData = drawingBitmap.LockBits(New Rectangle(0, 0, drawingBitmap.Width, drawingBitmap.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb)
        Dim dataStreamxx As DataStream = New DataStream(drawingBitmapData.Scan0, drawingBitmapData.Stride * drawingBitmapData.Height, True, False)
        Dim properties As Direct2D.BitmapProperties = New Direct2D.BitmapProperties()
        properties.PixelFormat = New Direct2D.PixelFormat(DXGI.Format.R8G8B8A8_UNorm, Direct2D.AlphaMode.Premultiplied)
        result = New Direct2D.Bitmap(WRT, New Size(drawingBitmap.Width, drawingBitmap.Height), dataStreamxx, drawingBitmapData.Stride, properties)
        drawingBitmap.UnlockBits(drawingBitmapData)
        Return result
    End Function
    Public Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        F = New Direct2D.Factory()
        WRTP = New Direct2D.WindowRenderTargetProperties()
        WRTP.Handle = Me.Handle
        WRTP.PixelSize = Me.PixelSize
        WRT = New Direct2D.WindowRenderTarget(F, WRTP)
    End Sub
    Public Sub Form1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Paint
        WRT.BeginDraw()
        WRT.Clear()
        If Not IsNothing(TheBitmap) Then
            WRT.DrawBitmap(TheBitmap)
        End If
        WRT.EndDraw()
    End Sub
    Sub Main()
        Dim Command As TCP.Command
        While True
            If TCP.Listener.Pending() Then
                TCP.Clients.Add(TCP.Listener.AcceptTcpClient())
                TCP.Streams.Add(TCP.Clients.Last().GetStream())
            End If
            For a=0 To TCP.Clients.Count-1
                If TCP.Streams(a).DataAvailable Then
                    Command=TCP.ReadCommand(TCP.Streams(a))
                    If Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Command.Command) = "Bitmap"
                        TheBitmap=LoadBitmap(New Bitmap(New MemoryStream(Command.SubCommands(0))) 'Convert it.
                        Me.Invalidate()
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        End While
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. Not really, but I just translated it again, exactly same, and it works.